# Joint probability of different sums of same set of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, correlation

X is a vector of N independent normally distributed random variables (X<sub>1</sub>...X<sub>N</sub>), where X<sub>i</sub> ~ N(μ<sub>i</sub>, σ<sub>i</sub>). Y is a vector of length K, where Y<sub>j</sub> is a sum of a subset of X. What is the probability that every Y is less than some value z?

I'm not quite sure what the technical terms are for what I'm looking for, or how to approach it. Y<sub>1</sub> will be correlated to Y<sub>2</sub> if they share a common subset of X, and that correlation can be calculated, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

If it makes it easier, assume Y just has length 2 (K=2).

Comment: Independence of $X_i$ implies that they jointly follows a multivariate normal. $\mathbf{Y}$ is an affine transformation of $\mathbf{X}$, so $\mathbf{Y}$ also follows a multivariate normal. Hence, you just need to compute the resulting mean vector and covariance matrix of $\mathbf{Y}$ first, and then find a software to compute the joint CDF, evaluated at the point $\mathbf{z}$.

Comment: Thanks BGM. Is it still a multivariate normal if **Y**i is the sum of some Xs? And I am hoping to solve for the joint CDF at a one-dimensional point z, not a vector of points **z**. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes they are still multivariate normal. But as you have mentioned in the question, in general there maybe some "common" $X_i$ which make those $Y_j$ are not independent, hence it is quite hopeless to reduce the problem into the univariate normal CDF (unless $Y_j$ are independent). I do not think that choice of $\mathbf{z}$ will help, unless it is exactly the mean vector.